# Reg - Error Input Past End of File - VbScript

Tags: vbscript

I wrote a simple program to write and read data from text file using `FileSystemObject`, but it doesn't work and gives me a runtime error:

> Input Past End of File.

Kindly let me know the mistake I made here.

```
'Here is the Program - 

Dim Fso    'Reference obect to File system
Dim TxtObj 'Reference to Text stream object
Dim Txt    'Reference to Text stream object to open file
Dim i      'To Read Text in file

Set Fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set Txtobj = Fso.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\Project Folder\NewText_3.txt")

Txtobj.Write("Hello")

Txtobj.Close

Set Txt = Fso.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\Project Folder\NewText_3.txt",1)

Do while Txt.AtEndOfStream<>1
  i = Txt.Read(1)
Loop

Msgbox i

Txt.close
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Option Explicit ' safety belt

Const FSpec = "14481096.txt" ' dry the file name

Dim Fso 'Reference object to File system
Set Fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim TxtObj 'Reference to Text stream object (used for rwrite and read)
Set Txtobj = Fso.CreateTextFile(FSpec)

Txtobj.WriteLine "Hello"
Txtobj.Close

Dim Letter 'To Read Text in file (each letter)
Set Txtobj = Fso.OpenTextFile(FSpec)  ' ForReading is the default, no need for magic number 1)
Do Until Txtobj.AtEndOfStream ' never compare boolean values against boolean literals
                              ' or - worse - values of other types you *hope* VBScript
                              ' will convert correctly
   Letter = Txtobj.Read(1) ' letter
   WScript.Echo "got", Letter
Loop
Txtobj.Close
```

output:

```
cscript 14481096.vbs
got H
got e
got l
got l
got o
got     <-- aka cr
got     <-- aka lf (in case you are wondering)
```

Extra hint:

```
>> WScript.Echo CInt(True), CInt(False)
>>
-1 0
>>
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot, I made some changes in the below program i.e. am writing text till end of stream instead of Reading, and I get an run time error - Bad File Mode.

Comment: Dim Fso  'Reference obect to File system

Dim TxtObj 'Reference to Text stream object

Dim Txt 'Reference to Text object file

Set Fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set Txtobj = Fso.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\Project Folder\NewText_5.txt")

Do until Txtobj.AtEndofStream

Txtobj.Write("Hello")

Loop

Txtobj.Close

Comment: @user1925406 fortunately, there is no concept 'till end of file' if you are writing.